# I keep getting an error "error starting at line 2 in command:" i cant see the error here and this is stopping me from creating my table

Tags: sql, oracle

--Create lecturer table

```
create table lecturer
( 
   lec_id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   lec_name        VARCHAR2(22),
   lec_grade       NUMBER(6,0),
   lec_salary      NUMBER(8,2),
   dept_code       VARCHAR2(10),
   lec_start_date  DATE
);
```

Comment: How are you running this command?

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Looks to be valid Oracle SQL, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55aea/1.